# SQL filling a table importing data from another table and math

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develop software for one of my classes.

It is supposed to create a table `contrato` where I would fill the info of the `clients` and how much are they going to pay and how many payments they will make to cancel the contract.

On the other hand I have another table `cuotas` which should be filled by importing some info from `table1` and I'm trying to perform the math and save the payment info directly into the SQL. But it keeps telling me I cant save the SQL because of **error #1241**

I'm using PHPMyAdmin and Xampp

Here is my SQL code

```
INSERT INTO `cuotas`(`Ncontrato`, `Vcontrato`, `Ncuotas`) SELECT (`Ncontrato`,`Vcontrato`,`Vcuotas`)  FROM contrato;
SELECT `Vcuotaunit` = `Vcontrato`/`Ncuotas`;
SELECT `Vcuotadic`=`Vcuotaunit`*2;
```

Can you please help me out and fix whatever I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign value to a column in select statements? If you want to change certain values in a field, then use an update statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! In order to get a proper answer, you would need to increase the quality of your question ; please [have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Providing sample data and expected results (both as tabular text) is a must for sql questions.

Comment: Try `UPDATE \`cuotas\` SET \`Vcuotaunit\` = \`Vcontrato\`/\`Ncuotas\`;
UPDATE \`cuotas\` SET \`Vcuotadic\`=\`Vcuotaunit\`*2;`

Answer (score 1):

Those selects are missing a FROM clause.
So it's unknown from which table or view they have to take the columns.

You could use an UPDATE after that INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO cuotas (Ncontrato, Vcontrato, Ncuotas)
SELECT Ncontrato, Vcontrato, Vcuotas
FROM contrato;

UPDATE cuotas
SET Vcuotaunit = (Vcontrato/Ncuota),
    Vcuotadic = (Vcontrato/Ncuota)*2
WHERE Vcuotaunit IS NULL;
```

Or use 1 INSERT that also does the calculations.

```
INSERT INTO cuotas (Ncontrato, Vcontrato, Ncuotas, Vcuotaunit, Vcuotadic)
SELECT Ncontrato, Vcontrato, Vcuotas,
 (Vcontrato/Ncuota) as Vcuotaunit,
 (Vcontrato/Ncuota)*2 as Vcuotadic
FROM contrato;
```